# Бекенд язык для веба

Tags: python, node.js, веб-программирование, ruby, backend

Доброго времени суток!
Не могу разобраться в одном вопросе: хочу выбрать бекенд язык для Веба (сайты, веб-приложения). ПХП сразу откидываю, так как много о нем наслушался и контингент не радует. Не хочу никого обидеть. Опыта в бекенде 0. Есть, в частности, вопросы по поводу Python, Ruby, Node.js - с чего начать, что проще зайдёт и будет более-менее оптимальным вариантом? По-хорошему, хотелось бы выбрать такой язык, который имеет некоторые перспективы ещё и в других направлениях IT. (это также одна из причин, почему ПХП откинут). Много листал форумы, но все они превращались в срач и уже было непонятно, что выбирать. Всё что, прошу, у кого есть опыт разработки, скажите, какой язык проще в освоении (более-менее) и актуальный.
Спасибо!

Comment: здесь такие вопросы нельзя. А вообще без разницы, попробуй что больше понравиться писать

Comment: Да кого вы там слушаете?

Comment: "Много листал форумы, но все они превращались в срач и уже было непонятно, что выбирать." Вот именно. Поэтому подобные вопросы здесь просто закрывают. Берите любой из перечисленных. В случае чего, переучитесь.

Comment: Легче заходит Python или Go Lang. Игнорировать PHP как минимум глупо, так как слишком много сайтов на нем, да и все основные CMS также на нем написаны.

Comment: Если хотите стать профессиональным бэкэндщиком, то пхп знать нужно, имхо. Если просто как хобби, то начните с питона

Comment: Дорогой однофамилец!
Определись какие именно цитирую "другие направления IT" тебя интересуют. и- станет проще. 
Я лично - за Python но посмотри в сторону C#.

Answer (score 0):

**Доброго времени суток.**

Самым оптимальным языком под бекенд в вебе это **PHP**, он изначально разрабатывался для подобных целей и оптимизирован под них (работает быстрее, чем другие).

**Node.js** - это попытка сделать, фронтенд язык JavaScript под бекенд.
( работает относительно медленно, требует много серверной мощности )

**Python Django** - по моему скромному мнению ( каждая лягушка свое болото хвалит ), немного превосходит Node.js
 
( проще и быстрее проходит разработка за счет самой идеи питона простое упрощай ). Много готовых модулей, документации как на русском, так и на анг. языке. 
Применяется при работе с "**Большими данными (BigData)**" в крупных компаниях. 
Вот только в периферийных городах python developer(ы) требуются редко.

Вообще опять же выбирайте исходя из целей сайта, если нужно написать что то быстро, берите **питон**, если будет высоконагруженный проект тогда **php**, если хотите написать на **Node.js** подождите пару лет, когда его немного оптимизируют.

Comment: Ощущение, что ответ прямиком из 2015. nodejs уже довольно шустрый. К тому же, намного прощее питона.
Про "если будет высоконагруженный проект тогда php" - это вообще смешно (:

Comment: Работал на том и другом в нескольких компаниях, так что считай ответ на основе продакшен опыта.

Comment: У нас nodejs на сервере для онлайн игры. php по сравнению с ним отдыхает.

Comment: Возможно, худшее, что можно сделать с серверным фреймворком, — написать его на JavaScript. (С) =)                                                      Проект в открытом доступе, могли бы его скинуть ссылку, даже интересно стало?)

Comment: Steam версия http://store.steampowered.com/app/446270/UnnyWorld__Battle_Royale/

Comment: Suvitruf, вообще довольно прикольно вышло, сколько разрабатывали и сколько разработчиков трудились над шедевром?

Comment: Разработчиков 3. 3 года делаем.

Comment: Suvitruf, У вас есть какая-нибудь почта? Хотел бы немного поспрашивать по поводу игры, если время найдете